# How to save a JSON-response from a REST-client in Codeception without using PhpBrower

Tags: php, rest, response, helper, codeception

I'm trying to test my own Rest-API using a Client-library which handles the requests for me.
I've written a helper in which the Client gets initialized and a action is added called "wantToGetUserOverClient($userId)". The client does the request and returns a JSON, that works as intended when I var_export() the JSON.
I've tried to extend the Rest module and assigning the public response field directly but get an exception:

```
[ModuleException] PhpBrowser: Page not loaded. Use `$I->amOnPage` (or hidden API methods `_request` and `_loadPage`) to open it
```

My Question:
What is the best way to save the Client response in the Codeception REST module response so I can use the already existing JSON-actions. 
For example:

```
$I->wantToGetUserOverClient(1234);
$I->canSeeResponseIsJson();
```

without loading a Page withe the PhpBrower.

Thanks in advance.

**My helper:**

```
class ApiHelper extends \Codeception\Module\REST
{
    private $backendApi;

    public function __construct(ModuleContainer $moduleContainer, $config = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($moduleContainer, $config);
        $this->backendApi = new BackendRestAPI();
    }

    public function wantToGetUserOverClient($userId)
    {
        $this->response = $this->backendApi->user()->one($userId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misusing REST module.
But if you insist, you have to replace PhpBrowser with your module.
Configuration:

```
REST:
  depends: YourModule
```

To make `seeResponseIsJson` work, `YourModule` must extend `Codeception\Lib\InnerBrowser` and implement `_getResponseContent` [method](https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/blob/2.2.9/src/Codeception/Module/REST.php#L620).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and solution. It works and I could build a working solution with it. 
One last thing, I know I'm misusing the REST module. 
I should make the requests over the PHPBrowser so everything works like intended, but if you had to test the Client also what would be "best practice"? 
Separate Tests for Client and the Webservice?

Comment: Yes, you should really separate tests of client and webservice.